# loadDataWithBaseURL blank result

Tags: android, webview

I'd like to load a website in webview with UTF-8, because I'm having accentuation problems, so I'm trying:

```
myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/constituicao/constituicaocompilado.htm", "", "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

but the result is a blank screen.

If I use loadURL("site") it loads, but I have accentuation problems. any ideas?

edit --

my webview setup:

```
WebView myWebView = findViewById(R.id.webView1);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

  public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />

    </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you briefly describe the accentuation problems please? Page looks fine to me (with and without setting utf-8).

Comment: @MarkusPenguin in my tablet some words like "é" will become `?`. but it works in my android phone. in emulator the accentuation becomes `?` too.

Comment: I updated my answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use `loadUrl` to load the link.

`loadDataWithBaseUrl` is not meant to load the given `baseUrl` into the `WebView`. It is meant to load the data that you pass as `data` into the `WebView` ([documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#loadDataWithBaseURL(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))). Say you want to have "Hello World!" written in your `WebView`:

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(url, "<html><body>Hello World.</body></html>", null, "UTF-8", null)
```

Regarding the encoding: when using `loadUrl` you should not need to set `UTF-8` explicitly because [it is the default](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setDefaultTextEncodingName(java.lang.String)). Using `ISO-8859-1` worked for the specific page you want to load:

```
webSettings.defaultTextEncodingName = "ISO-8859-1"
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer! I edit my question with some more details. maybe the website I'm trying to load nas no charset defined, I don't know.

Comment: The trick was to use ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8. I've updated my answer.